# Не могу считать строку в массив структур

Tags: c++, функции, указатели, структуры, динамические-массивы

Видимо вся проблема в том, что размер массива я также читаю из файла (тобиш он динамический), и когда я пытаюсь считать строку через getline компилятор начинает ругаться. Как исправить?

```
using namespace std;

const char *FNAME = "text0.txt";

struct PLANES
{
    char time;
    char plane_name;
    char serial;
    int fly_num;
};


int main()
{
    int File_Inf[3];
    streampos position;

    ifstream fin(FNAME);

    fin >> File_Inf[0] >> File_Inf[1];

    fin.close();

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    system("color F0");

    PLANES *mass = new PLANES[File_Inf[0]];

    return 0;
}

void MakeArray(int *File_Inf, streampos position, PLANES *mass)
{
    ifstream fin(FNAME);

    int i;
    int lines = File_Inf[0];
    int str_len = File_Inf[1];

    fin.seekg(position, ios::beg);

    for (i = 0; i < lines; i++)
    {
        fin.getline(mass[i].time, 5, ' ');
    }
}
```

> Ошибка: отсутствуют экземпляры перегруженная функция ... , соответствующие списку аргументов: (char, int, char)

Answer (score 0):

У функции getline другие типы параметров:
getline (char* s, streamsize n, char delim );

Используй streamsize, а не int.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/streamsize/